# How does the program move forward if the variable is declared false?

Tags: ruby, variables, boolean

How does the program continue beyond ''bear_moved = false''? If the while statement only runs while true how can the program continue to run? Or is the while true unrelated to the 'bear_moved'? If so what does it relate too?

```
def bear_room
  puts "There is a bear here."
  puts "The bear has a bunch of honey."
  puts "The fat bear is in front of another door."
  puts "How are you going to move the bear?"
  bear_moved = false

  while true
    print "> "
    choice = $stdin.gets.chomp

    if choice == "take honey"
      dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
    elsif choice == "taunt bear" && !bear_moved
      puts "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
      bear_moved = true
    elsif choice == "taunt bear" && bear_moved
      dead("The bear gets annoyed and chews your leg off.")
    elsif choice == "open door" && bear_moved
      gold_room
    else
      puts "I got no idea what that means."
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `true` is a boolean value representing the boolean value `true`. The `while` runs while `true` is truthy, which is always.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to me that you want something like the following:

```
def bear_room
  puts "There is a bear here."
  puts "The bear has a bunch of honey."
  puts "The fat bear is in front of another door."
  puts "How are you going to move the bear?"
  bear_moved = false

  until bear_moved
    print "> "
    case gets.chomp
    when "take honey"
      dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
    when "taunt bear"
      puts "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
      bear_moved = true
    when "open door"
      gold_room
    else
      puts "I have no idea what that means."
    end  
  end
  puts "I'm outta' here!"  
end

def dead(str) puts(str) end
def gold_room; puts "So this is the famous gold room. Nice."; end
```

Some points to consider:

- since you have `while true`, you need a `break` statement to exit the loop.  Alternatively, you can use `until bear_moved`, as I have done.  If you want to use `while true` (or more idiomatic, `loop do`), just replace `until bear_moved` with `break`. I've written it differently just to show you the choice available.
- you don't need an `if bear_moved...else...end` under `when "taunt bear"`, because `bear_moved` is always `false` at the point.
- there is no method or local variable `dead` or `gold_room`, so you need to do something about that.  I've added methods for those.
- I've used a `case` statement instead of all the `if-elsif`'s because it is easier to read. Also, you see you don't need the variable `choice` when using a `case` statement.  I've also included only the outcomes of `choice`, leaving the secondary choices in `if-then-else`'s for two of the `case` outcomes.

(I initially had `while bear_moved == false`. I changed that to `until bear_moved` after reading @SteveTurczyn's answer.  Thanks, Steve.)

Comment: You're welcome, Cary. :) Good analysis of the program.

Answer (score 2):

```
while true
```

is another way of saying

```
while true == true
```

which of course, is always and perpetually true. You can only come out of a `while true` loop via an explicit `break` command.

What you want to do (I think) is...

```
until bear_moved
```

Meaning you will continue to loop until you've executed the `bear_moved == true`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're failing to grasp the concept of "state", the status that things are in.  Initially the bear is (implicitly, according to text) in front of the door.  The state of the bear is "unmoved from its initial position", and is captured by the boolean variable `bear_moved` which is set to the value `false`.  The `while true` will continue to repeat the contained logic indefinitely until you give a command which results in the bear moving or the bear killing you. It looks like the correct sequence of actions is to taunt the bear - if it hasn't moved, as indicated by the `bear_moved` state variable, it will move, but it if has already moved and you taunt it again the bear will get annoyed and chew your leg off.

Basically, the chain of logic that gets followed depends on the state, i.e., in this case the interaction between the status of the bear (moved or not) and your action choice.